# How to mount a samba share over an ssh tunnel?

Tags: mount, ssh, samba

I have created an ssh tunnel in such a way, that I can access my shares by typing

```
smb://bruni@localhost:9000/
```

into the filemanager (dolphin). The tunnel works.

I would like to mount this share. The following command does not work:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/root/.credentials,uid=bruni,gid=users,vers=1.0 //localhost/users /home/bruni/mountpoint/
```

Obviously I need to specify the port somewhere.
How can I modify the above command so that it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add port=the port to the mount command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o port=9000,credentials=/root/.credentials,uid=bruni,gid=users,vers=1.0 //localhost/users /home/bruni/mountpoint/
```